# Error merging multiple CSV files - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

I'm trying to merge several CSV files into one.

Searching several methods, I found this one:

```
files = glob.glob("D:\\green_lake\\Projects\\covid_19\\tabelas_relacao\\acre\\*.csv")
files_merged = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df) for df in files], ignore_index=True)
```

When running this error is returned:

```
>>> files_merged = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df) for df in files], ignore_index=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper    
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 678, in read_csv 
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read    
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1253, in read    
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 225, in 
read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 243, saw 4
```

I'm starting to study python and if it's a stupid mistake, I apologize ;)

Comment: maybe use normal `for`-loop to display filename before loading file - to see which file CSV makes problem. Error may suggest that some file is incorrectly formatted. It gets row with one column but previous rows had 4 columns. You may have to open this file in any text editor to see what can make problem and manually correct it.